# SQL query with joins that shows only rows until 23.11.2020

Tags: mysql, sql

I created this query and it only takes rows until date 23.11.2020 doesn't take more then 2-3 hundred rows.

```
SELECT a.datum
     , a.cas
     , a.domaci
     , a.hoste
     , a.stream
     , b.name
     , b.color2
     , c.jmeno
     , d.firstname as first1
     , d.lastname as last1
     , e.firstname as first2
     , e.lastname as last2 
  FROM zapasy a 
  JOIN projekt b 
    ON b.id = a.projekt 
  JOIN televize c 
    ON c.id = a.televize 
  JOIN tipuser d 
    ON d.id = a.komentator1 
  JOIN tipuser e 
    ON e.id = a.komentator2 
  JOIN projekt_role f 
    ON f.userid = $uid
 ORDER 
    BY datum DESC
     , cas ASC
     , domaci asc
     , projekt asc
     , stream ASC
```

Is there some kind of limit in SQL that just won't show me some rows if I use too many JOINS ?

Comment: Maybe your client limits the amount of retrieved/displayed rows?

Comment: or maybe some table in your joins has data till that date

Comment: @AkinaI couldn't find any limits. I am displaying a larger amount of rows on other pages without problems. (not with that many joins)

Comment: Were there always 2 kommentators or was that requirement dropped recently?

Comment: @P.Salmon always. I just used much crappier way to get those names. (creating another querry)

Comment: See about sql injection and the importance of prepared and bound queries

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing your data we can't diagnose this. But these aren't too many joins at all.

Suggestion: Remove your joins, one at a time, and look at the results. If, at any stage, you will get the rows that you are now missing, then you can try to find out why that particular join filtered them out.

Comment: or change them to `LEFT JOIN`s and see if he gets more data

Comment: @TAM  So I removed the 2nd JOIN on tipuser table and it started to work. The problem is that I kinda need that data. Any ideas how to workaround this?

Comment: @MarekLanger use a `LEFT JOIN` instead of an `INNER JOIN` there

Comment: @Lamak when I try to use the LEFT JOIN it only returns values for the first tipsport table JOIN and NULL's for the 2nd

Comment: @MarekLanger well....yes, because the other table doesn't have data